# How to store additional information in SCNNode?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am writing an iOS application using ARKit and SceneKit on iOS 11(beta).

This application adds many items onto an augmented reality scene. In order to identify each of these item, I subclassed SCNNode as MySCNNode and put an `id` field in it:

```
MySCNNode: SCNNode {
    var id: Int
    ...some initializer to assign value to the id
}
```

I also implemented a `touchesBegan` delegate method. When user touches a item, I want to retrieve its corresponding `id`. So I tried cast that item's corresponding `SCNNode` back to `MySCNNode`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    // hitTest to retrieve item's id
    if let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: sceneLocationView) {
        DDLogDebug("received touch location")
        if let hit = sceneLocationView.hitTest(touchLocation, options: nil).first {
            DDLogDebug("received a hit")
            if let scnNode = hit.node as? SCNNode {
                DDLogDebug("received a scnNode)")
                    if let mySCNNode = scnNode as? MySCNNode {
                        DDLogDebug("received a MySCNNode") // ====> Never reaches here
                    }

            }


            return
        }


    }


}
```

However, the step to cast from `SCNNode` to `MySCNNode` never happens

Did I wrote some place wrong when trying to cast the SCNNode back to MySCNNode in the above hit test? Is there any alternative way to store additional information in a SCNNode and later retrieve it ?

Thank you

Comment: "In order to identify each of these item"  Use the name property in the scene view.

Comment: Just a detail for anyone googling here! You wouldn't call it "MySCNNode". You'd call it TeddyBear, Tank, Squirtle, or whatever it is!

Comment: @Fattie: a lot of coding examples use exactly this convention of prepending "My" to a class name when talking about subclasses in the abstract. Whether it's a TeddyBear or a Milkshake is unimportant for the sake of the example, so this is fine.

Comment: hi @p10ben  Sure, perhaps I should have typed "In actual game code on iOS, you name those by the physical object, `TeddyBear`, `Tank` etc.   BTW I miss watching Ben10 !

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need `id`. Instead you could use existing `name` attribute. But if you want to check type of node, you should also check it's parents, because of `hitTest` result node starts from the child. You could add SCNNode extension:

```
extension SCNNode {
    /// Returns parent node of specified type.
    ///
    /// - Returns: An optional `SCNNode` of specified `T` class type.
    func parentOfType<T: SCNNode>() -> T? {
        var node: SCNNode! = self
        repeat {
            if let node = node as? T { return node }
            node = node?.parent
        } while node != nil
        return nil
    }
}
```

And then use:

```
if let myNode = node.parentOfType() as? MySCNNode {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track but you don't need so many casts and it's easier if you "stack" the `if let`s. Try this:

```
if let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: sceneLocationView),
    let hit = sceneLocationView.hitTest(touchLocation, options: nil).first,
    let myNode = hit.node as? MySCNNode {
    DDLogDebug("received a MySCNNode")
}
```